# How to fire selectionchanged before button's click?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have a GridView. It's datatemplate is a grid, that contains a button.
The problem is, that the button's click event fires before the gridview's selectionchanged, so i have no access to the correct selected item from the click eventhandler.
I'd like to work with the gridview's selected item when the button is clicked.
How can i make it?
Maybe find the sender button in the gridview? How can i do that?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Button's datacontext, that inherits the selecteditem's datacontext, so i'm fine.